# Are operations with the internal pointer of shared_ptr atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-ptr

Is it safe to copy and reset shared_ptr at the same time?

Namely consider the following code

```
// Main thread (before creating any other threads)
shared_ptr<A> a(new A(1));

// Thread 1
shared_ptr<A> a_copy = a;

// Thread 2
a.reset(new(A(2));
```

where thread 1 and 2 run in parallel. Can I be sure, that `a_copy` will store pointer either to the older `A(1)` or to the newer `A(2)` shared object?

Comment: As I remember when I read Jossuttis, he always pointed that STL-containers are not thread-safe / developer should always care about their safety.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy shared_ptr is not a container, and dislike container it has an atomic member (counter), so I beleive the pointer is also atomic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment)
>   can be called by multiple threads on **different instances** of `shared_ptr`
>   without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies
>   and share ownership of the same object.

So, the answer is no — these operations are not thread-safe because both the copy and the reset are applied to the same instance, `a`. The result is a data race, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right: data race in this context could mean that `a_copy` will have ref_counter from original `a` and pointer to data from `a` after reset. I had to RTFS to get this...

Comment: @PiotrNycz Sorry for copying your post…

Comment: @PiotrNycz So why did you delete your post?

Comment: @Potatoswatter wait, I don't understand. If they are `thread-safe`, how can the result be a data race?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Sorry, copy-paste error. Extreme laziness.

Comment: @Potatoswatter np :) It seems I am an answer-killer in this topic - commented to 2 answers which are deleted.. Why don't they just edit them?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Probably for the same reason I wrote my answer by copying and modifying Piotr's: the extra effort just doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy I deleted mine because it would be identical to Potatoswatter's post - that will not help future readers to have two identical answers...

Comment: @PiotrNycz well, I've thought your answer was first.. So you could just edit it.. But okay, I got you.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not, see @Potatoswatter answer.

But if you *do* need to atomically operate a `shared_ptr`, you can use [these dedicated functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). (Although AFAIK they are only implemented on recent versions of GCC/Clang).

So your example would be:

```
// Main thread (before creating any other threads)
shared_ptr<A> a(new A(1));

// Thread 1
shared_ptr<A> a_copy = atomic_load(&a);

// Thread 2
atomic_store(&a, make_shared<A>(2) );
```